# Symfony QueryBuilder - exclude objects having specified object connected to it?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Symfony 2.8. I have `ExternalReference`, which has its `type` and can be attached to some objects. Like this:

`Entity\ExternalReferenceType.php`:
 - `$id`
 - `$name` (string)

`Entity\ExternalReference.php`:
 - `$id`
 - `$value`
 - `$type` (`ManyToOne` to `ExternalReferenceType`)

Now, something I attach references to, `Entity\ObjectWithReferences.php` has the following, apart from `$id` and other fields:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\ExternalReference")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="obj_references",
 *     joinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="obj_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *          },
 *     inverseJoinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reference_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *          }
 *     )
 */
private $references;
```

*(OneToMany unidirectional assotiation, as far as I remember, I found it in Doctrine's documentation)*:

Now user will pick one of reference types (`ExternalReferenceType` object) and I want to list all `ObjectWithReferences` objects which **don't have any** reference of that type. I'm a bit lost, I *probably* could do it in plain SQL, but I need it in `QueryBuilder` format. Can you help me?

Comment: By the way, the DB is quite huge, so trying to do it with `$qb->expr->notIn()` with DQL selecting all objects having reference of that type will cause OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: If you're able to do that with plain SQL, then provide such query that's result would be satisfiable for you. By the way, as I understand what you want is simple `NOT IN`, but then you say in your comment that it's not what you want. I'm confused.